# release the calling thread while calling async function in synchronous context

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, async-await

It seems it is impossible in c# (dotnet core 3.1) to call an asynchronous function from a non-async method without blocking the original thread. Why ?

Code example:

```
public async Task myMethodAsync() {
  await Task.Delay(5000);
}

public void callingMethhod() {
  myMethodAsync().Wait(); // all flavours of this expression, like f.ex. .Result seem to be blocking the calling thread
}
```

What is the technical limitation for being able to release the calling thread until the async method completes, and then continue execution from there? Is it something technically impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems it is impossible in c# (dotnet core 3.1) to call an asynchronous function from a non-async method without blocking the original thread. Why ?

Because that's what synchronous *means*. Synchronous means it blocks the thread until the method is complete.

> What is the technical limitation for being able to release the calling thread until the async method completes, and then continue execution from there? Is it something technically impossible?

If your calling method wants to release its thread, then make it asynchronous. Asynchronous methods are capable of releasing their calling threads. There's nothing impossible here; it's been solved by `async` and `await`.

Now, if you're asking "why can't every method implicitly be `async`", then that is in theory possible, but it causes a couple of major issues. It can never be done in C# for backwards compatibility reasons. The two issues that immediately come to mind are:

1. Limited interop. It's not possible to use an "everything is `async`" language to interop with anything that uses old-school threading (Win32 mutexes, et. al.).
2. Unexpected concurrency. There are a *lot* of scenarios where developers make an assumption of synchronous code. If *every* method is potentially asynchronous, then even code as simple as `var x = this._list[0]; this._list.RemoveAt(0);` is no longer safe.

Comment: Appreciate this. It seems to me that the guarantee of synchronicity by disallowing unexpected asynchronicity could in this light be viewed as more of a desirable feature rather than a technical limitation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is expected. That is *why* the concept of `Task` etc exist. If it was possible to do what you want: *they wouldn't need to* - we could just wave a wand and everything would be async. The entire point of awaitable types is that releasing the calling thread while allowing later continuation is *hard*, and requires coordination and participation from the calling code; and from what ever calls that; etc - all the way up the stack to whatever is running the threads. Your `callingMethhod` code is synchronous: it has only a few things it can do:

- it can run to completion - meaning: it would have to block
- it can throw an exception

The impact of this is that `async`/`await` is infectious; anything that touches awaitables *kinda needs to also be awaitable*, which means: you would typically only call `myMethodAsync` from a `callingMethhod` that returned a `[Value]Task[<T>]`, and which is presumably `async` with an `await` (although those bits aren't strictly necessary in the example shown).

Comment: I would love to hear more on why this is the case. I.e. why does it have to be like that and why would it be "hard" to allow the continuation ?

Comment: @JKJ simply: *what would that look like?* what would actually happen? where would the call-stack go next, if the async thing is incomplete? what happens to the result of `myMethodAsync` (whether that means a return value, or an exception)? does whoever called `callingMethhod` also know that things are unwinding? if so: how? it can only see a `void` - it knows nothing about the task. In terms of call semantics: awaiting in the middle of a sync flow just ... can't be done; you can *block* (via `.Wait()` or `.Result`), but you really really shouldn't (it is explicitly a very very bad idea)

Comment: @JKJ to put this into context - it may help to illustrate *just how complex async is* - here's something similar to your code, but with two `async` methods; now look in the right hand pane, which shows what the compiler did to make it work - it is *really, really complicated*, because scheduling async continuations is inherently a complicated affair: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+BYAUAAQAwAEOAjAKwDc2OAzEQEwEAK2A3tgR0bTgBxFIEAsgE9BMAC4ALCABMAggGdhAOzAAKAJTtObLJ044AnPwB0AERgAbAIbC1pPI42U9nAL7ZtHGkT44BAMLWlpYAlsoA5mJS0jKaXgS6+vpGQqISsYoq6s4JHlhuQA===

Comment: "what would happen?" I was trying to picture it like this, the thread's state is stashed until the async function returns. Then the stash is popped onto an available thread and execution continues where it left off. So basically same as currently async/await works. I'm guessing its not possible but this is where my understanding of what the concept of a thread constitutes to fully understand why it is not possible. But the other answer here seems to be pointing at some backwards compatibility conflicts as well as resource locking which is probably the issue.

Comment: Also ref your other questions: from a simplistic perspective, without appreciating what happens on which thread, the only visible difference between synchronous calls and awaited async calls is that in async you have to deal with the entire abstraction of the Task object and it's various states, but still in most use cases you're only interested in the actual returned payload or confirmation of completion, which is mostly the same as in synchronous calls isn't it ?

Comment: @JKJ it is incredibly hard to stash the thread state - you need to understand a *lot* of call semantics - and you can't just interrupt a thread, fake away the data, and say "you're done, now you're doing something else". Storing and unrolling the thread state are *what awaiters enables* - again: that's *why the concept exists*. Without that kind of API; this is not something you can just do magically.

Comment: @JKJ also keep in mind: the machinery required to enable await is *not free* - it would be **massively** harmful for performance to just say "everything is now async magically, by the compiler; if you returned void, you now return ValueTask, etc"; it would also not be binary compatible - it would break the world, if you see what I mean. It isn't even *possible*: there are things you *cannot do* in an `async` method, because the state cannot be stored - anything involving ref-locals, for example - or because of thread semantics - anything that uses `lock`, for example